# Router Vue is not transfering from.params to route

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

so i have sth like this:
in router:

```
{
    path: '/feature',
    name: 'CustomFeature',
    component: CustomFeature,
    pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true },
    meta: {
        title: Custom features,
        scrollToTop: true,
    }
}
```

in product component (template):

```
             <a @click="createNewFeature">go</a>
```

and then:

```
createNewFeature() {
    this.$router.push('/feature#new')
}
```

and in my CustomFeature component:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
          console.log(from) // - here is problem
...
```

[image]

it should show me that is going from "product site" route

i tried changing

```
<a @click="createNewFeature">go</a>
```

to just

```
<router-link to="/feature#new">go</router-link>
```

or

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/feature#new' }">go</router-link>
```

but it doesnt work i tried to add children to '/feature' path in router but i dont know how to do it properly (and if it is a case)

Comment: I nearly had a stroke reading this. The `from` is your previous route. So it depends where you're starting from. If your product component is shown when accessing your base_url , your path-from is basically `/`. Could you please clarify what you actually want to achieve, and where you're coming from, when clicking this link.

Comment: from product component im going to feature component

and i dont get it in 

`beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
          console.log(from)` in my feature component